# A part of model broken whilst posing

Tags: mesh, object-mode

Is there any way I could fix this issue easily? I discovered a part of my model was broken whilst I've been posing it. I reset the pose to default and fixed the object, but it still goes a bit deformed once it's back in its pose.

[image]

Improvement:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the mesh of your belt is not closed, you should delete some vertices and use <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Bridge*. Also, it's not parented to the good bones. You should join it to the rest of the body <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, select your belt in *Edit* mode, remove from any group in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Vertex Groups* and *Remove From All Groups* function, then in *Weight Paint* you assign it to the bones that you want i.e. same bones as this part of the body) with the *Limit Selection to Visible* option disabled (on the horizontal menu bar) so that it paint the vertices you can't see.

Comment: I've closed the gap and joined it with the torso. Adding Weight Paints has helped a bit, but it's still a bit wonky. I've added another pic to the original post.

Comment: I've tested and it works, so you must have skipped a step, I've edited my answer, you need to remove from any group: in Edit mode select your belt and in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups and Remove From All Groups function, then in Weight Paint you assign it to the bones that you want with the Limit Selection to Visible option disabled (on the horizontal menu bar)

Comment: Thank you. That's fixed the issue nicely. :D Also, that Remove from All Groups option is useful. I didn't know it was there.